# How many centiMorgans should we share?

Tags: centimorgans

Sally and Sidney are our great grandparents. Their daughter Susan is my grandmother and her Brother Peter is my cousins grandfather. Susan's son Frank is my father and my cousins Mother is Ruth. Frank's son (me) and Ruth's son John therefore sit at the same level in the family tree.

Both Ruth and her son John have had DNA tests, however ancestry,com are reporting that I share only 234cM's with Ruth and 128cM's with John. Technically Ruth should be my first cousin 1x removed and John my second cousin (right?), but the cM's are telling another story, one which says we're not as closely related as our family lines suggest. Is this correct?

On contacting John he was a bit reluctant to communicate with me, but did confirm that Peter was his Grandfather.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/128 a match of 128cM is indeed a second cousin with 14% probability. So it's not the most likely relationship but neither is it that unlikely.

And 234 cM is 9% probability to be a 1st cousin once removed.

So the DNA is absolutely not contradicting your paper genealogy.

Statistics are like that - there are always people at the more unlikely end of the scale of whatever it is - otherwise we'd all know someone who can run as fast as Usain Bolt.